# CMS to Choose for setting up an online bookstore

Tags: content-management-system, e-commerce, store, opencart

i want to setup a online bookstore something like www.flipkart.com . But my initial focus is books only.Initially the inventory is going to be moderate but i plan to make it huge with time.(Buy the way amazon is not available in my country that is india ). I want to give most options of online purchasing using payment gateways also options like cash on delivery other common stuff.

i know php mysql javascript and little css for designing. I have a really small budget for website construction.And i have never made a ecommerce website before.

so my question is what is the way to go. I know a little about magneto , opencart , zencart , oscommerce , prestashop (googling for hours gave me these results). What should i choose and advantages or disadvantages of choosing it. Please note i am not good in themeing so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OSCommerce has being the most popular choice in the last couple of years, but i see a constant growth in developers using Magento. I have never tried Magento myself, but from my OSCommerce experience - its pretty easy to set up.

But their system indeed looks very nice :) 
Maybe someone with Magento could give out some more info on his views.